# MVC Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SQL command wherein I am trying to join multiple columns in a single table which is,

```
 dbo.tbl_Application AS APP on (APP.motor_no = SUBSTRING(R.remarks, CHARINDEX('|', R.remarks) + 1, LEN(R.remarks))) AND (Year(APP.date_created) = YEAR(R.txndate)) AND (APP.motor_no = M.motor_no)
```

Now I converted it to Linq

**CONVERTED TO LINQ**

```
join APP in db.tbl_Application on new 
 { motor_no = R.remarks.Substring(5), R.txndate.Value.Year, motor_no2 = M.motor_no }
 equals new 
 { motor_no = APP.motor_no, APP.date_created.Value.Year, motor_no2 = APP.motor_no }
```

And then added to my existing linq which is:

**EXISTING LINQ**

```
from R in db.vwEtracs_Receipt
join RI in db.vwEtracs_ReceiptItem on new { parentid = R.objid } equals new { parentid = RI.parentid }
join IA in db.vwEtracs_IncomeAccount on new { objid = RI.acctid } equals new { objid = IA.objid }
join M in db.vwQVFS_Motor on new { motor_no = R.remarks.Substring(5) } equals new { motor_no = M.motor_no } into M_join
from M in M_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join OOI in db.vwQVFS_OOI on new { operator_id = R.payerId } equals new { operator_id = OOI.operator_id } into OOI_join
from OOI in OOI_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join CR in db.vwQVFS_COR on M.motor_id equals CR.motor_id into CR_join
from CR in CR_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join F in db.vwQVFS_Franchise on new { or_id = R.objid } equals new { or_id = F.or_id } into F_join
from F in F_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join T in db.vwQVFS_TODA on M.toda_id equals T.toda_id into T_join
from T in T_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join RT in db.vwQVFS_RT on new { payer_id = R.payerId } equals new { payer_id = RT.payer_id } into RT_join
from RT in RT_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join B in db.vwQVFS_Brand on M.brand_id equals B.brand_id into B_join
from B in B_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

If I include the line of code from above, I am getting the error `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` but if I remove it, my Linq works perfectly.

What is making causing this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SQL query itself shows there's a *big* design problem - instead of using proper keys, at least one column stuffs multiple pieces of information insto one field. That violates even the 1st Normal Form, prevents indexing and offers *no* guarantee you can get correct results. Fix the *tables* first so you don't have to process text instead of joining

Comment: I can't see any hardcoded `5` in your SQL query, but I can't see it in your LINQ query

Comment: Besides, LINQ isn't SQL. It's a language *on top* of an ORM. The *ORM* should define relations so you don't have to use joins. If you do it's a very clear sign there's something wrong with the entity model

Comment: @Rafalon all that string parsing guarantees off-by-one errors. Although it's  likely that the same bad joins are used in the views and the error is thrown by *them*. What if there was *no* `|` ? Or it's the *last* field? That's not generated by LINQ

Comment: I also can't understand why one would write `new { parentid = R.objid } equals new { parentid = RI.parentid }` instead of `R.objid equals RI.parentid`. This is introducing so much noise in code...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was trying to connect it link app.motor_no to r.remarks and m.motor_no. If this is the case then I should probably change my table. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MaceMunch what ORM are you using? LINQ *does not query databases*. EF? Linq-to-SQL? EF would *refuse* to execute `R.txndate.Value.Year` because it can't be mapped to SQL as is. I suspect it's L2S that loads *all the table data in memory* and then tries to use LINQ to Objects to find matches.

Comment: @Rafalon The code was left outer join, I just did what I saw in a blog about Left Outer Join in Linq. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @MaceMunch you should change the table and entities. You are working with ORMs which means *entities* not tables. `Receipts`, not `vwQVFS_TODA`. Create *proper* entities with relations and let the *ORM* do its job

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EF sir

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried to place into a View the table that was in a different db. I searched connecting context to context but found out that it can be troublesome so I just referenced all the necessary data in the other database to this entity using Views

Comment: @MaceMunch much easier then to create a *different* context with that database's views. And since this looks like an ERP query, if you want to match specific item types use a separate field for the item type. Don't try to extract the type from the invoice or part number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting the error because there is at least one record shorter than 5 characters in your database db.vwEtracs_Receipt.remarks column. So in your SQL, you don't pass length actually but in your linq you use Substring(int length). So the substring length can't be longer than the actual string length

Comment: Upon inspection, I saw one data that resembles exactly as your answer. Thanks